# Running Scripts or Commands in Spinnaker Pipelines

Tags: amazon-web-services, automation, amazon-ecs, continuous-deployment, spinnaker

I'm trying to run scripts as part of some of my deployment pipelines in Spinnaker. I don't want to use Jenkins to run these scripts. I would use a Kubernetes job, but these scripts need to execute prior to the Kubernetes deployment.

I was debating creating ECS tasks in AWS which I'd like to run on demand during one of the stages in my pipeline. Does anyone know if it's possible to execute an ECS task directly from Spinnaker?

If not, are there any other ways to execute a command or script in a pipeline outside of using a Kubernetes job or Jenkins server?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use the Run Job ( Manifest ) stage and just point it to another kubernetes cluster for this. This approach gives you a bit of flexibility since you can monitor the pipeline stage for completion status.

You can also just create an arbitrary API endpoint and trigger via a webhook stage that monitors for completion and use whatever your preferred script execution environment (i.e, Lambda, ECS etc) behind that api endpoint.